# Can indexes be created in batches using py2neo

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

I am using py2neo to upload the initial data into neo4j and am using batches to make it faster. I was wondering if there is a way to create indexes too using batches.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a good solution for this. The `WriteBatch()` has the method `add_index_node`
eg,

```
batch = neo4j.WriteBatch(graph_db)  
a = batch.create(node(name='Alice'))  
batch.add_index_node("people","name","alice",a)  
batch.submit()
```